# Why is a computer monitor less suitable for use with video game consoles, compared to a TV?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

I have heard that TVs are better suited for game consoles (such as the PS3 or Xbox 360), rather than computer monitors.

Is this the case? if so, Why? Is it just because of screen size or does it have something to do with the screen refresh rate?

Comment: Can you please clarify the statement that "computer screens are not suitable for video games"? The XBox is not a video game - it is a video game *console*. Do you mean to ask why console games are better played on TV screens than computer monitors?

Comment: I quite happily played PS3 connected to a 22" PC monitor for a couple of years. There was nothing wrong with it at all. It helped that the monitor suppored HDMI and had built-in speakers though.

Comment: Your question is a bit confused though. You don't need a PC at all to play console games on a computer monitor. You just plug the monitor directly into the console.

Comment: I edited the word CONSOLE into your title because I'm rather certain this is what you meant. If I have somehow misunderstood your intent please feel free to roll-back the edit and clarify your question.

Comment: -1, the question is unanswerable since your assertion itself is wrong (computer monitors work fine for gaming). Perhaps rephrase asking if they are unsuitable, and if so which ones?

Comment: Better how? I prefer computer monitors over TV screens. (see how this is all subjective?)

Comment: I edited your question to remove the subjective assumptions, and to clarify it. Just edit back parts of the question I removed, if you think it's too much. (I removed that bit of your question which is confusing [to me].)

Comment: Did this guy just post the same question six times?

Answer (score 4):

Technically there is no difference between Monitors and TVs, however, due to the way some games are programmed, there can be a significant difference in the gaming experience - most significantly for FPS games.

Since consoles have quite bad performance, the developers use a lot of tricks to increase the framerate. One of those tricks is reducing the Field of View (FOV), i.e. the angle that the player can see in front of him. PC games usually use 80 degree, console games are around 60 degree. From a low distance, i.e. when you sit right in front of a Monitor, the low FOV can cause headaches and nausea for some players but from a longer distance, i.e. your couch to a TV, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't think FOV has anything to do with framerates, just the typical viewing distance. See here: http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/MatthewBlevins/20100709/87645/Making_Proper_PC_Versions_of_CrossPlatform_Games.php

Comment: @congusbongus Well it can, but it all depends on implementation of the game engine. Because the FoV is lower, the engine has to do a part less rendering because it is not vissible to the player. Now this might be only a little fraction, but every little bit might help.

Answer (score 1):

A modern TV is a monitor with some extra circuitry (tuner, embedded player for videos, etc), there is no reason for monitors to be worse at displaying console video than TVs. Having built-in speakers or an audio out if you're using HDMI will be necessary.